# InfluxDB Measurements Have Incorrect Time

Tags: go, time-series, influxdb

I'm having some issues with incorrect time stamps in InfluxDB. I receive data from a websocket connection, create a new point for each response, and upload each point to a bucket. When I look at the points in the InfluxDB UI, I notice that the time field is incorrect. Here are 4 examples of unmarshalled responses that I received from the websocket connection, as well as the time field in its respective point:

```
&types.TradeResponse{ChannelID:337, TradeArray:[]types.TradeDataResponse{types.TradeDataResponse{Price:21567.4, Volume:0.00553002, Time:time.Date(2022, time.August, 26, 3, 49, 29, 0, time.UTC), Side:"b", OrderType:"m", Misc:""}}, ChannelName:"trade", Pair:"XBT/USD"} 
point time:  2022-08-26 03:49:29 +0000 UTC

&types.TradeResponse{ChannelID:337, TradeArray:[]types.TradeDataResponse{types.TradeDataResponse{Price:21567.4, Volume:0.0372093, Time:time.Date(2022, time.August, 26, 3, 49, 43, 0, time.UTC), Side:"b", OrderType:"m", Misc:""}}, ChannelName:"trade", Pair:"XBT/USD"} 
point time:  2022-08-26 03:49:43 +0000 UTC

&types.TradeResponse{ChannelID:337, TradeArray:[]types.TradeDataResponse{types.TradeDataResponse{Price:21567.3, Volume:0.00045028, Time:time.Date(2022, time.August, 26, 3, 49, 59, 0, time.UTC), Side:"s", OrderType:"m", Misc:""}}, ChannelName:"trade", Pair:"XBT/USD"} 
point time:  2022-08-26 03:49:59 +0000 UTC

&types.TradeResponse{ChannelID:337, TradeArray:[]types.TradeDataResponse{types.TradeDataResponse{Price:21567.3, Volume:0.00010686, Time:time.Date(2022, time.August, 26, 3, 50, 7, 0, time.UTC), Side:"s", OrderType:"m", Misc:""}}, ChannelName:"trade", Pair:"XBT/USD"} 
point time:  2022-08-26 03:50:07 +0000 UTC
```

and here is a picture of the points in the bucket: [image]

As you can see, the `_time` field is always slightly off from the time in the point. I'm currently using the go client to upload data to the DB. Here is the code that I have written for that:

```
func OnTradeResponse(data types.TradeResponse, tradesWriter api.WriteAPI) {
    for _, trade := range data.TradeArray {
        point := influxdb2.NewPoint("trade", map[string]string{"object": "trade", "pair": data.Pair}, map[string]interface{}{"price": float64(trade.Price), "volume": float64(trade.Volume), "side": trade.Side, "orderType": trade.OrderType, "misc": trade.Misc}, trade.Time.Time)
        tradesWriter.WritePoint(point)
        log.Println("point time: ", point.Time())
    }
}
```

If I was just using the system time when creating new points, I could understand why there might be an issue with having an incorrect time, but since I'm using the time from the trade response as the time in the point, I don't understand what is causing the issue. Would greatly appreciate any help

Comment: The image appears to be rounding the time to 10sec increments.

Comment: Can't believe it was so simple, but the UI has it automatically set to a 10s window. Just updated it to 1s and it works as it should now. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I was going mad about this. I need to learn more about this window concept. I expected the times show to be the ones I set, but my window was set automatically to 4m9s998ms so the times were off, but not massively.

Comment: Such a strange window for it to be set to @テッド